# Find an efficient algorithm in terms of reduce Big O complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, nested-loops

Given a sorted array of N elements. Need to find the absolute sum of the differences of all elements.
Eg : given 4 elements 1,2,3 and 4. |1-2|+|1-3|+|1-4|+|2-3|+|2-4|+|3-4| = 10. Here is my code in java :

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //just for understanding , the Array List is already filled with numbers 
public static int lsum(int N)//consider the arraylist to be sorted in ascending order.
{
    int sum =0;

    for( int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        int w =a.get(i);
        for(int j =i;j<N;j++)
        {
            int z = a.get(j);
            sum =sum +(z-w);
        }

        }
    return(sum);

}
```

Looking for an efficient algorithm rather then the trivial one I am using { O(n^2) complexity}. This is a requirement of a bigger program which requires this function. The input (number of elements) can be as big as 10^5.

Comment: Please go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel not much help there,haven't received any answers hence re posted.

Answer (score 1):

If you sort the elements first, you can get the runtime down to `O(n log n)`.

The idea here is that if `a[]` is the list of integers in sorted order and `b[i]` is the sum of the differences between `a[i]` and the other numbers, then `b[i+1]` can be computed directly in terms of `b[i]`, `i`, `a[i+1] - a[i]`, and the length of the array.

I won't say exactly how, but here's a hint. How much can `Math.abs(a[i+1] - a[j])` differ from `Math.abs(a[i] - a[j])`? For which `j` is `Math.abs(a[i+1] - a[j])` greater? For which `j` is it smaller?

Now, after you compute those, the `b[i]`s then among themselves contain each difference twice.  The value you want is just their sum divided by 2.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is `x_1 <= x_2 <= .. <= x_n`

The sum of terms involving `x_r` is `U_r + (2r -n) x_r - L_r`

where `U_r = x_{r+1} + x_{r+2} + ... + x_n`
and `L_r = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_{r-1}`

Now You can compute all `U_i` in O(n) time in one pass through the array. `L_i` can be written in terms of `U_i` and total sum of the elements.

Thus the whole sum can be computed in O(n) time.

Some playing around with math should give you a *single* pass algorithm.

(I leave the details to you).